# Toast from ListView behaves in an unexpected way

Tags: android, listview

This is a simple code that I use to populate the files in a directory using `Listview` . And when the user **clicks** the element in list, The name is Toasted, and `finish()` is called to end the `Activity`. But the **problem** is when the user clicks every elements in the list, it Toasts the name of every clicked element. And I wonder what happens to the `finish()` method? Here is my source code. *please comment below for any additional info!*

```
 private List<String> myList;
File file;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rec_lister);




        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listX);
        myList = new ArrayList<String>();

        File directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        file = new File( directory + "/myAppCache/" );
        File list[] = file.listFiles();

        for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
        {
            myList.add( list[i].getName() );
        }
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                view.animate().setDuration(2000).alpha(0)
                        .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run()
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + item,
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                finish();


                            }
                        });
            }
        });

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, myList);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter); //Set all the file in the list.
}
```

Comment: what is the result if you try finish(); outside run method.

Comment: Call Activity.finish(); Please read it  [enter link description here][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304927/android-ending-activity-from-within-rendering-thread

Comment: Call ActivityName.finish() and follow this link [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304927/android-ending-activity-from-within-rendering-thread

Answer (score 0):

Use `ActivityName.this.finish();`

You are inside an anonymous inner class remember. So, you need to reference the activity you want to finish explicitly.

Only `finish();` finishes the `Runnable` object. not the activity.

So, use the `<ActivityName>.this.finish();`

Comment: After a list Item is clicked, the Activity is supposed to be destroyed with the Toast? That is your aim?

Comment: Try writing the `ActivityName.this.finish();` method after `view.animate().setDuration(2000).alpha(0).withEndAction();` method.

Answer (score 0):

Its may be due to calling `finish()` inside a `Runnable`, try doing this way:

```
YourActivity.this.finish();
```

Comment: That was my first instinct, and I did try that, but no use